# Node js - How to serve multiple SVG files to a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, svg

I'm new to Node and server oriented code and am trying to get multiple svg files which are stored in the server.

Here is my code client-side using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: someURL,
  data: someData
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log('data got', data);
  callback(null, data);
})
.fail(function() {
  callback(new Error('Cannot access files'));
});
```

And here is my code server side:

```
// links is an array of links to the different svg files
var svgs = [];
async.eachSeries(links, function(link, next) {
  fs.readFile(link, function(err, svg) {
    svgs.push(svg);
    next(err);
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    response.writeHead(500);
    response.end(JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end(svgs); // Doesn't work
  // response.end(svgs[0]); // Works
});
```

As long as I send only one file to the browser (which seem to be a Buffer instance), everything seems to work fine, but when I try to send multiple ones as an Array the transaction succeed but I got nothing in my returned data. That may be related to the MIME type of what I'm trying to send, but I couldn't find how to handle that.

Comment: Can you try looping thru the SVGs and write them individually? Like for each svgt { response.write(svg) } response.end()

Comment: What server side framework do you use? Doesn't look like express/connect to me. What should the result look like? Should the svgs be in a JSON array? Or concatenated as one string?

Comment: @IzaazYunus indeed it worked fine the way you suggested, but I eventually adopted a JSON stringify.

Comment: @hgoebl I'm using express, maybe not the proper recommended way yet. I wasn't sure about what format to expect, usually I just get served by all the magic that happens server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to convert `svgs` into a `String` or `Buffer` first. One option is to stringify it as JSON:

```
response.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
response.end(JSON.stringify(svgs));
```

This is because [`response.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding), which [`response.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) is calling to handle the `data` (`svgs`), doesn't accept `Array`s.

> `chunk` can be a string or a buffer. If `chunk` is a string, the second parameter specifies how to encode it into a byte stream. By default the `encoding` is `'utf8'`.

Whereas each `svg` provided by `fs.readFile()` is a `Buffer`, so it has no issues writing `svgs[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it worked that way, I guess I was secretely wondering it there would be a built-in format more efficient for svgs than plain string.

Comment: AFAIK `response.end` should not be used in express. I had problems (request hung) and eliminated all `.end` calls. If it's JSON, `response.json` has the advantage of adding `Content-Type: application/json` automatically.